# How do I create a working Docker Image from html, css, js files?

Tags: docker, web-hosting, docker-image

I'm completely new to Docker but for university purposes I needed to code a website (html, css, js) and eventually need to provide it as docker-compose configuration. I've watched countless hours of tutorials and questioned chat gpt extensively but every time I build an imagine and launch it used to get redirected to the nginx index.html page. Now after some more tries I've somehow managed to manually copy my index.html into the Docker image, but neither my styles.css nor my scripts.js are found when starting up a new container. I am completely lost at this point.

Dockerfile:

```
`FROM nginx:latest
RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf

COPY index.html /var/www/html/index.html
COPY styles.css /var/www/html/style.css
COPY scripts.js /var/www/html/script.js

EXPOSE 80

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]`
```

nginx.conf:

```
`server {
    listen 80;
    server_name test.local;
    index index.html;
    root /var/www/html;
}`
```

and my docker-compose.yml:

```
`version: '3'
services:
    web:
    image: nginx:latest
    volumes:
        - "./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf"
        - "./code:/var/www/html"
    ports:
        - "80:80"`
```

Within Docker Desktop itself my logs show this error:

```
2023/06/30 11:09:37 [error] 20#20: *1 open() "/var/www/html/styles.css" failed (2: No such file or directory)
2023/06/30 11:09:37 [error] 21#21: *2 open() "/var/www/html/scripts.js" failed (2: No such file or directory)
```

Answer (score 0):

### Dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx

COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/

COPY index.html /var/www/html/
COPY styles.css /var/www/html/
COPY scripts.js /var/www/html/
```

#### Explanation:

- You shouldn't remove `default.conf`.
- Since the names of your files on your local machine are gonna match with those inside the container, you can completely omit the names of the files inside the container.
- `EXPOSE` and `CMD` instructions are already provided in the base `nginx` image. Unless you wanna do something else, you generally shouldn't be explicit there.

### docker-compose.yml:

```yaml
services:
  web:
    image: nginx
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/:ro
      - ./code:/var/www/html
    ports:
      - 80:80
```

#### Explanation

- `version` declaration can be omitted since docker-compose version `3`.
- The nginx config has been made *read-only* inside the container (which is pretty much a common norm).

`nginx.conf` looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

With your setup, the Dockerfile is completely ignored.  You're using the unmodified `nginx` image, and then trying to inject files into the container using `volumes:`.  It's worth noting that the file paths in the Dockerfile and Compose file don't match: the `volumes:` hide the image's `/var/www/html` directory and replace it with the host's `./code` directory, but the Dockerfile copies files out of the build-context directory and not a subdirectory.

You need to tell Compose to `build:` the image; you do not need to specify the `image:` name unless you're planning to push the image somewhere (and you definitely should not set `image: nginx` which will cause the base image to be overwritten).  You should remove the `volumes:` so that you're using the files actually built into the image.

```yaml
version: '3.8' # most recent version supported by all Compose implementations
services:
  web:
    build: .  # add
    ports:
      - '80:80'
    # image: registry.example.com/myimage  but only if you're planning to push it
    # no volumes:
```